# load a pickle file in a sub package --> error with module '__main__'

Tags: python, flask, import, pickle

I get this error message when I try to load a pickle file:

```
Can't get attribute 'CustomNMF' on <module '__main__' from '/Users/cricket/Documents/ONline classes/A6 - Stackoverflow/Tag-generator-Stackoverflow/app.py'
```

My question where am I missing an `import CustomNMF` or any other thing that would make it work ?

It's a flask project I'm working on, the structure is:

project folders:

```
+ app.py
+ app (sub-folder)
++ __init__.py
++ views.py
++ CustomNMF.py
++ and other things...
```

Content of `app.py`:

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

content of `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

Content of `views.py`:

```
....
from app.CustomNMF import CustomNMF
customNMF = CustomNMF()  #That works fine !

def loadpickle(filename = 'customNMF.pickle'):
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'app', filename), 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

customNMF = loadpickle('customNMF.pickle')  #Line that is generating the error :-(
....
```

Content of `CustomNMF.py`: (A simple copy paste from the notebook used to create the `class`)

```
class CustomNMF(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,popularitytags=None, **params): 
        self.popularitytags = popularitytags
        .......
```

I'm sure it's obvious for most of you, and the solution is just a small detail I'm missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `customNMF = CustomNMF()  #That works fine !` - really?  how do you know?  If it does work, do you realise you are masking one `CustomNMF` name with another?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue: I saved the `customNMF` trained from the python notebook. I had to slightly modify the classes in the `dask` version not not call some unnecessary packages (cross validation and metrics from `sklearn`) for the website version.
I assume those minor modifications are the source of the problem.

Now the CustomNMF is trained and pickled for later usage by the website server. Not sure it's the best approach, but it's working!

If anyone as good lecture about packages structure and how to articulate them (simplified version ;-) just for me), I would really appreciate.

Thanks